# Assessing relationship between a binary outcome and a continuous predictor, given probability distribution of the predictor

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, modeling

I have a distribution of binary outcomes (say, car accidents at a several locations) over time for a set period (two years) with each outcome ascribed a date. I'm wanting to compare these against meterological predictive variables, and have the daily weather for each of the said locations. I'm trying to work out how to disentangle the predictive power of each meterological variable (if there is one), given its underlying probability distribution.

[image: Example probability distributions]

For example, the distributions of mean daily humidity over the whole time-frame, for all locations (>21k datapoints) and the mean daily humidity when there is a car accident (~8k datapoints) is plotted above. Both distributions look fairly similar, and are when compared with a KS test. Is this sufficient to say that there is no correlation between humidity and the chance of a car accident, or should I adjust the distribution of car accidents to remove the inherent distribution in daily humidity?

Comment: One "hacky" way to do this would be to break your humidity variable into bins and convert it into a categorical variable which allows you to use Chi-Squared test (or all the other tests meant for contingency tables)

Comment: I notice this question was never answered, but I have a similar problem. Do you mind sharing the solution you ended up using to get around this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to CV SE. Please be aware that using answer for comment is not warranted.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/328246)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/328247)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach to this would be to calculate whether or not an accident occurred on each day (or the number of accidents, if there are enough days with $>1$ accidents). You can then use logistic regression (or Poisson regression, if you're using the number of accidents) to test whether there's a relationship between daily humidity (the predictor) and whether an accident occurs that day (the outcome).

Of course, in this case it might be that accident rates and humidity both fluctuate throughout the year but humidity doesn't directly cause accidents, so you're going to have to deal with that confound as well, but that's outside the scope of this question.